# @ViewScoped beans are not supported on stateless views

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, view-scope

I have a page in JSF:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:param name="navLinkActive" value="poiAdder"/>

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:outputStylesheet library="clock" name="clockpicker.css"/>
        <h:outputScript library="clock" name="clockpicker.js"/>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/lego/leftMenu.xhtml"/>

            <div class="col-md-10">

                <h:form id="poiForm" prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <h:outputLabel for="address"
                                       value="Adres"/>
                        <h:inputText id="address"
                                     styleClass="col-md-10"
                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.address}"
                                     requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldRequired}"
                                     required="true"/>
                        <input type="button"
                               class="btn btn-default"
                               value="#{msg.findAddress}"
                               onclick="codeAddress()"/>
                        <h:message for="address" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="longitude"
                                       value="Współrzędne (automatycznie)"/>
                        <h:outputLabel for="latitude"
                                       styleClass="descriptionLabel"
                                       value="podaj adres, a potem wybierz dokładną lokalizację na mapie, jeśli potrzebne"/>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h:inputText id="longitude"
                                         styleClass="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2"
                                         required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldRequired}"
                                         value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.longitude}"
                                         converter="javax.faces.Double">
                            </h:inputText>

                            <h:inputText id="latitude"
                                         styleClass="col-md-4"
                                         required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldRequired}"
                                         value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.latitude}"
                                         converter="javax.faces.Double">
                            </h:inputText>
                        </div>
                        <h:message for="latitude" style="display: block; color:red"/>
                        <h:message for="longitude" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="poiTypeSelector"
                                       value="Wybierz kategorię POI"/>
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="poiTypeSelector"
                                         styleClass="btn"
                                         value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.poiCategory}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{poiAdderBean.poiCategoryList}"
                                           var="poiCat"
                                           itemLabel="#{msg['poi'.concat(poiCat)]}"
                                           itemValue="#{poiCat}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:outputLabel for="phoneNumber"
                                       value="#{msg.phoneNumber}"/>
                        <h:inputText id="phoneNumber"
                                     style="width: 350px"
                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.phone}"
                                     validator="#{PhoneValidator.validate}">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="phoneNumber" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="linkwww1"
                                       value="Link www #1"/>
                        <h:inputText id="linkwww1"
                                     style="width: 350px"
                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.link}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="linkValidator"/>
                            <f:attribute name="linkDescritpion" value="#{description1}"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="linkwww1" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="linkwww1Description"
                                       value="Opis #1"/>
                        <h:inputText id="linkwww1Description"
                                     binding="#{description1}"
                                     style="width: 350px"
                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.linkDescription}">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="linkwww1Description" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="linkwww2"
                                       value="Link www #2"/>
                        <h:inputText id="linkwww2"
                                     style="width: 350px"
                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.link2}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="linkValidator"/>
                            <f:attribute name="linkDescritpion" value="#{description2}"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="linkwww2" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="linkwww2Description"
                                       value="Opis #2"/>
                        <h:inputText id="linkwww2Description"
                                     binding="#{description2}"
                                     style="width: 350px"
                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.link2Description}">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="linkwww2Description" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.openingHours}"/>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group clockpicker">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="from">DO</span>
                                    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control"
                                                 id="clockInputStart"
                                                 value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.openHoursStart}">
                                    </h:inputText>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="timeFrom">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group clockpicker">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="to">DO</span>
                                    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control"
                                                 id="clockInputStop"
                                                 value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.openHoursStop}">
                                    </h:inputText>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="timeTo">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h:outputLabel for="disableAccess"
                                           value="#{msg.disableAccess}"/>
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="disableAccess"
                                                     value="#{poiAdderBean.poi.disableAccess}">
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h:outputLabel for="titlePl" value="#{msg.polishTitle}"/>
                            <h:inputText id="titlePl"
                                         value="#{poiAdderBean.polish.title}"
                                         required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldRequired}"/>
                            <h:message for="titlePl" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h:outputLabel for="titleEng" value="#{msg.englishTitle}"/>
                            <h:inputText id="titleEng"
                                         value="#{poiAdderBean.english.title}"
                                         required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldRequired}"/>
                            <h:message for="titleEng" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h:outputLabel for="descriptionPl" value="#{msg.descriptionPl}"/>
                            <h:inputTextarea id="descriptionPl"
                                             value="#{poiAdderBean.polish.description}"
                                             style="resize: none"
                                             required="true"
                                             styleClass="form-control"
                                             rows="4"
                                             requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldRequired}"/>
                            <h:message for="descriptionPl" style="display: block; color:red"/>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h:outputLabel for="descriptionEng" value="#{msg.descriptionEn}"/>
                            <h:inputTextarea id="descriptionEng"
                                             value="#{poiAdderBean.english.description}"
                                             required="true"
                                             style="resize: none"
                                             styleClass="form-control"
                                             rows="4"
                                             requiredMessage="#{msg.description}"/>
                            <h:message for="descriptionEng" style="display: block; color:red"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h:inputFile styleClass="btn btn-default" id="file" value="#{poiAdderBean.uploadedFile}">
                                <f:ajax listener="#{poiAdderBean.uploadFile()}" execute="@this"/>
                            </h:inputFile>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 loginSubmit">
                        <h:commandButton styleClass="btnDefault"
                                         style="margin-top: 50px"
                                         value="#{msg.add}"
                                         action="#{poiAdderBean.createPoi}">
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[

            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
                placement: 'bottom',
                align: 'left',
                autoclose: true,
                'default': 'now'
            });

            var map;
            var marker;
            var geocoder;
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


            function initialize() {

                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.05923273190915, 19.92233544588089)
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                        mapOptions);

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                    setLatLong(event.latLng);
                    makeMarker(map, event.latLng);
                    codeLatLng(event.latLng);
                }); //end addListener

            }

            function makeMarker(map, latLong) {
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLong,
                    map: map
                });
            }

            function codeAddress() {
                var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
                if (address != null && address != "") {
                    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                            map.setCenter(location);
                            map.setZoom(18);
                            makeMarker(map, location);
                            setLatLong(location);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Nie podano adresu");
                }
            }

            function codeLatLng(latLng) {
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng': latLng
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;
                            console.log(results[0]);
                        } else {
                            alert('No results found');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }

            function setLatLong(location) {
                document.getElementById("longitude").value = location.lng();
                document.getElementById("latitude").value = location.lat();
            }
            //]]>
        </script>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

and bean for this page:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import java.io.*;

@Named("poiAdderBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PoiAdderBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    PrincipalBean principalBean;

    @Inject
    @Created
    Event<Poi> poiCreated;

    private Poi poi;
    private Translation polish;
    private Translation english;
    private Part uploadedFile;
    private Image image;

    public void uploadFile() {
        image = new Image();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        if (uploadedFile!= null) {
            try {
                InputStream is = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                    is.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "error uploading file",
                        null);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        }
        image.setContent(bytes);
        image.setContentType(uploadedFile.getContentType());
    }

    public Part getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(Part uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }

    public Poi getPoi() {
        return poi;
    }

    public void setPoi(Poi poi) {
        this.poi = poi;
    }

    public Translation getPolish() {
        return polish;
    }

    public void setPolish(Translation polish) {
        this.polish = polish;
    }

    public Translation getEnglish() {
        return english;
    }

    public void setEnglish(Translation english) {
        this.english = english;
    }

    public PoiCategory[] getPoiCategoryList(){
        return PoiCategory.values();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        poi = new Poi();
        polish = new Translation(Language.PL, Status.READY);
        english = new Translation(Language.EN, Status.READY);
    }

    public String createPoi(){
        english.setAuthor(principalBean.getLoggedUser());
        polish.setAuthor(principalBean.getLoggedUser());

        poi.addTranslation(polish);
        poi.addTranslation(english);

        polish.setPoi(poi);
        english.setPoi(poi);

        if(image != null){
            poi.setImage(principalBean.getDataAccess().mergeEntity(image));
        }

        principalBean.getDataAccess().mergeEntity(poi);

        poiCreated.fire(poi);

        return "/secure/poiTranslator.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

For some completely strange and unknown to me reason, there is always error message on a bottom of a page that says:

> @ViewScoped beans are not supported on stateless views

but this is clearly @SessionScoped bean. I can't find source of this error, that's why I posted entire code.

PLUS - when I don't upload a file - validation works just fine, and after successfully writing Poi object in database, page is redirected to poiTranslator page, just like it should. BUT when I add image - validation don't work, and page is not redirected - but objects are stored correctly in database.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well its not the entire code, you don't post what is inside that leftMenu.xhtml which gets included, and since this is a composition, there is also some sort of template probably that we're not seeing. A reference to a viewscoped bean may be in either of those. Regardless, the error seems to indicate that JSF 2.2's stateless mode is active for this view. That probably is not correct to begin with? http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/02/stateless-jsf.html

Comment: yep - it was template file.....

Comment: post your suggestion as an answer, and I'll chose it as a good one

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gimby I found small error in my template file. 
Like in post from BalusC blog he posted, in my template was line that was enabling statelessness - which was not wanted in first place.

Thanks for help.

[link to BalusC artickle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/02/stateless-jsf.html)

Comment: A side note just in case you didn't know yet: a tag in an answer does not notify anybody :) Also, please just include the link to BalusC's blog in your answer. The main purpose is to preserve the relevant information in a single answer and not in comments.

Comment: It is even 'required' to include the most relevant parts of the content of of the link to preserve information (if it does not violate copyrights)